# siliding image css and html only

Tags: html, css

i want the pic to slide to the left and top side and and not straight foward,
i am using only css and html without javascript.

and there is simple code to take make the "dropdown" li to go down and push the rest of the categories?

thanks fot helping guys !

```css
nav{
    background-color: #fff;
    width:150px;
    height: 667px;
    float:right;
}

nav h1{
    padding: 20px;
    color: #777;
    font: 20px tahoma,times,serif;

}
ul {
 position: relative;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 list-style: none;
 width: 150px;
 text-align: right;
 }
ul li {
 position: relative;
 }
li ul {
 position: absolute;
 right: 149px;
 top: 0;
 display: none;
 }
ul li a {
 display: block;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #777;
 background: #fff;
 padding: 5px;

 border-bottom: 0;
 }
ul {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 list-style: none;
 width: 150px;

 }
li:hover ul {
     display: block;
}

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body {
    background: #333;
    background: url("images/3.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.container{
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-right: 0;
    height: 500px;
     -webkit-box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    width: 800px;
}
.container img{
    margin-top: 0px auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: -60;
}
.container li img {
    margin-top: 0px auto;
    position: absolute;
    left: 600px auto;
    z-index: -50;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
    transition: all 1s ease;   
}

li:nth-child(1){
    padding-top: 0px;
}

li a:hover {
    background: #eee;
}

li a:hover + img {
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 0px auto;
    left: -667px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <LINK rel=stylesheet type="text/css" href="StyleSheet.css"/>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
        <nav><h1><b>text</b></h1>
  <ul>
  <li><a href="#">text</a><img src="http://media3.fcbarcelona.com/media/asset_publics/resources/000/160/456/size_640x360/pic_2015-01-11_BARCELONA-ATLETICO_45.v1431011244.JPG" alt="1"></li> 
  <li><a href="#">text</a><img src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTd6ngNNGapdLhqdS4KbuoNNCaaUMP4Svu-e_9rXMh_wLDtPpSE" alt="1">
      <ul> 
      <li><a href="#">text</a></li> 
      <li><a href="#">text</a></li> 
      <li><a href="#">text</a></li> 
      </ul>
      
    </li> 
  <li><a href="#">text</a><img src="http://static3.demotix.com/sites/default/files/imagecache/a_scale_large/2000-5/photos/1368393557-club-atletico-de-madrid-v-fc-barcelona--la-liga_2046465.jpg" alt="1"> 
      <ul> 
      <li><a href="#">text</a></li> 
      <li><a href="#">text</a></li> 
      <li><a href="#">text</a></li> 
      <li><a href="#">text</a></li>  
      </ul> 
    </li>
  <li><a href="#">text</a><img src="http://barcelonacamps.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/barca-new-team.jpg" alt="1"> 
      <ul> 
      <li><a href="#">text</a></li> 
      <li><a href="#">text</a></li> 
      <li><a href="#">text</a></li> 
      <li><a href="#">text</a></li> 
      </ul> 
      </ul>
    </li> 
            </nav>
        </div> 
    </body>
</html>
```

[the website](http://nicomoya.freeoda.com/)

Comment: What do you mean, `to the left and top side and not straight forward` ?

Comment: like in this demo  http://designshack.net/tutorialexamples/navpics/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand completely what you're trying to achieve, but check out this codepen: [Image Slider](http://codepen.io/cavanflynn/pen/KVXqPq?editors=010)

If you want them to slide up to the top left then just set the `top` attribute and adjust for how high:

```
li a:hover + img {
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 0px auto;
    left: -667px;
    top: -100px;
}
```

Can you explain `and there is simple code to take make the "dropdown" li to go down and push the rest of the categories?` more though.

Comment: i want it to be like in this demo www.designshack.net/tutorialexamples/navpics/index.html, your fix just moves it up at the end by 100px, its ok for the 1st pic, but there is still empty space for the others.